# Visual Studio does not open Resx files

Tags: .net, visual-studio

This is a `CLR Project` when I try to open a `resx file` on `Visual Studio` I get the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DataDesign.Common, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Info:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.8.3
```

Is that a missing workload from `Visual Studio Installer` that I should install?

These are the following workloads installed in my `Visual Studio`:

```
MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
Windows 10 SDK
C++/CLI support for v142 build tools
```

Comment: Explain how you “try to open a resx file”. Is it a resource in your project? A file in your folder? Are you double-clicking the file in Solution Explorer?

Comment: @DourHighArch Yes it's a resource in my project. That file is automatically generated with a UI form. I'm just double-clicking the file in Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by installing the following workload:

```
.NET desktop development/.NET Framework 4 - 4.6 development tools
```

Total space required roughly ~2GB.